# Clicking on editable table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a table in HTML. I have made this table as editable by using JavaScript. When the user clicks a cell, it will become editable. The problem here is, when the cell is already editable, if the user again clicks on the cell ...., some tags and other things appear. i.e. new text boxes appear for every click.

How this could be prevented?

I am using the following JavaScript code:

```
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
    //alert(tablecell.firstChild.nodeValue);
    tablecell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type=text size=\"6\" name=newname onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this);\" value=\""+tablecell.innerHTML+"\">";
    tablecell.firstChild.focus();
}
function submitNewName(textfield)
{
    //alert(textfield.value);
    textfield.parentNode.innerHTML= textfield.value;
}
```

Comment: What tags and other things? You'll need to be more specific here I think.

Comment: Please edit your answer and format your code, thus post the elements that appear when you re-click the editable cell...

Comment: I am sorry. I thought, the code was displayed in the right format. modified it.

Comment: I deleted my answer so others can have a fresh try, as my initial assessment was incorrect. It should work as you posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If new text boxes are appearing after every click, your code is not taking care of the case: if the cell has an input text box already, then don't continue entering additional HTML for the input text box when the user clicks on the cell.

One way to prevent this could be setting the class of the table cell to a class name like "editable" at the end of your changeContent function. Then you can have code in the same function that will only put in the HTML for the input text box if the tablecell.className is not "editable".

Remember in your submitNewName function, to also remove the "editable" class name for the cell after the user is done editing.